# Several people sharing the same title...is the title plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

If you have a sentence that is referring to several people who share the same title, does the title become plural?

We are pleased to announce the promotion of John, Bob, and Joe, to the position of Associates.

We are pleased to announce the promotion of John, Bob, and Joe, to the positions of Associate.

We are pleased to announce the promotion of John, Bob, and Joe, to the position of Associate.

Comment: When unsure, I find it's easiest to reword:  "We are excited to announce our new Associates, John, Bob and Joe following their promotion"  or similar

Comment: As Lucy Kellaway once wrote, “leave your excitement for the bedroom”. And leave multiples for the mathematicians.

Answer (score 25):

*The position* they are being appointed to is titled *Associate* so this would be correct:

**"We are excited to announce the promotion of John, Bob, and Joe to the position of Associate."** (Leave out your comma before *to.*)

Alternatively, you could talk about their individual positions:

"We are excited to announce the promotion of John, Bob, and Joe to *their new positions as Associates*."

Each one *is an Associate*, and they *are all Associates*. Each one *has the position of Associate*.

Comment: Also, "We are excited to announce our new Associates: John, Bob, and Joe.".

Comment: I agree that the third version is most correct of the three. In addition, however, I would pluralise "promotion" to make it more explicit that there are three promotions to the same position.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "We are excited to announce the promotion**s** of John, Bob, and Joe to the position of Associate"?

Comment: @Vikki Promotion [(uncountable, countable) promotion (to something) a move to a more important job or rank in a company or an organization.](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/promotion). I'd use it in the uncountable fashion here, just like I would with "The group is dedicated to the promotion of small business, entrepreneur ship, and industry standards." Promotion as the act being done by the board (or whoever) rather than speaking of each individual *promotion* of the person or thing. Though it may also be correct to use the plural.

Comment: [Ngram favors *promotion of employees* over *promotions of employees* but both are certainly used.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=promotion+of+employees%2C+promotions+of+employees&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpromotion%20of%20employees%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpromotions%20of%20employees%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 3):

GArthurBrown's answer is entirely correct, though I would like to add that titles **are** pluralized when they are used before the names in question. For example:

"We are pleased to introduce *professors* Einstein and Newton."

"*Doctors* Kahneman and Anderson are the foremost modern psychologists."

"The suspects were taken into custody by *officers* Walker and Trivett"

Comment: I assume Kahneman and Anderson have doctorates, and while Walker and Trivett are technically Texas Rangers, I felt "officers" was a more appropriate example

Comment: And let's also add "Messrs Brown and Smith graced us with their waffles."

Comment: You could repeat the title with each name, as an alternate style, right?

Comment: @GarrettMotzner Certainly. "President Joe Biden and President Vladimir Putin will meet to discuss the terms of a new treaty."